# How to capture previous values of columns in a GridView in C#

Tags: c#, gridview

After updating a row, I am trying to save the previous values of that row.

In other words, I came up with the following code bellow to grab the values of the labels in the grid-view. This code in

```
gridview1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string Name = "";
    string day = "";

    string Session_name = ((Label)gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("Name")).Text;
    strSession_Name = Session_name;
    string Session_type = ((Label)gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("day")).Text;
    strType = Session_type;
}
```

When edit is clicked the labels turn into drop-down controls where the user can choose a different value. Later, after the user chooses the new value they want, they will click update. This will override the old value. However, when update fires I need somehow to save the old value to a string before it changes to the new one. when the update is running, RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) is executed and the above values are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do the following

```
Session["Name"] = ((Label)gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("Name")).Text;
Session["Day"] = ((Label)gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("day")).Text;
```

Then reference the Session["Name"] and Session["Day"] inside RowUpdating